# pulldown menu to pass two query strings

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to make a form with two different query strings.  So far I can make each pulldown menu pass one string at a time with onChange.

Is there a way to have a submit button pass both variables simultaneously?  Like onSubmit and the page goes to "www.address.com/cal?event=var1&date=var2" thanks!

My code so far:

```html
<form name="eventSearch" method="get">
  <select id="event" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="">all events</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?event=event1">event1</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?event=event2">event2</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?event=event3">event3</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="month" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="">Current Month</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?date=2014-09">September 2014</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?date=2014-10">October 2014</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?date=2014-11">November 2014</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?date=2014-12">December 2015</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?date=2015-01">January 2015</option>
    <option value="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?date=2015-02">February 2015</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `select` elements as they were intended, to pass values as part of the form's submission:

```html
<form name="eventSearch" method="get" action="http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month">
  <select name="event" id="event" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">all events</option>
    <option value="event1">event1</option>
    <option value="event2">event2</option>
    <option value="event3">event3</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name="date" id="month" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">Current Month</option>
    <option value="2014-09">September 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-10">October 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-11">November 2014</option>
    <option value="2014-12">December 2015</option>
    <option value="2015-01">January 2015</option>
    <option value="2015-02">February 2015</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve ::ie to get two different values to the same url
You can use Javascript to post/get the result ie

```
<button type="button" id="submit" >submit</button>

$('#submit').click(function(){
    var event = $('#event').val();
    var date =  $('#month').val();
    $.get("http://www.whateverwebsite.com/cal/month?event=" + event + "?date=" + date,function(response){
           response = JSON.parse(response);
           //do anything with response
    });
```

});